# Principled volume shader's weird behavior in Eevee

Tags: materials, shaders, volumetrics

I applied a material with Principled Volume (or Volume Scatter) shader only to the cube but it seems like the whole world is affected too.

This only happens with EEVEE render or in *Material Preview*, it works fine when I render with Cycles though.

I sent the file to a fellow blenderer and it actually had no problem on his computer, so I think this has to be my laptop or settings.

EEVEE without the cube:
[image: without the cube]

EEVEE with the cube:
[image: with the cube]

Solutions I've tried:

- Creating new file with factory settings.
- Using another version (Blender 2.9 beta)

Rendering with Cycles works fine

Cycles without the cube:

[image: Cycles without the cube]

Cycles with the cube:

[image: Cycles with the cube]

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) about possible hardware issues? (Look for the "If you have problems running Blender on your computer"). You can edit your question to add missing information by clicking on the "edit" link right below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that it was a driver problem. My games were running well, so I didn't think the driver was the cause. I updated the AMD driver to the newest version, and the problem is totally gone. I should've done this in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this seems like a bug but only with some types of hardware. I updated Blender to 2.83.5 which was released yesterday and am so happy that they fixed it. However, it only works with newly created files. Old files still have the problem sadly.

Edit: I don't know if they really fixed it or not but I tested again and sometimes it worked sometimes it didn't.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the task/bug if you have it around?

Comment: @brockmann I read the changelog but found nothing related. Also I edited the answer, it's just buggy so I'm not sure they acknowledged the problem.